# Android EditText click, keyboard scroll to different view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText. When I click on it, the input keyboard shows up with the EditText directly above it. I want the keyboard to show up a little bit further down at another View, as if the keyboard is focusing on that. Is there a way to handle this?

My use case is I have two EditTexts and a Button in vertical LinearLayout. I want it so that when I click on either of the EditTexts, the keyboard will popup and still show all three Views.

Comment: you could put the edittexts in a scrollview, then when your edittext is focused, do scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0, button.getBottom())

Comment: YOur only options when the keyboard comes up are:  do nothing, resize the app in the remaining space (which causes a new layout), or pan so that the cursor is on screen.  There is no way to assure a different view is on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice, you won't want that, i.e showing all views while the keyboard is showing. This will force android to squeeze the views when there isn't enough space.
Best option is try adding `paddingBottom` to your `EditText` an example being `android:paddingBottom="15dp"` This should align the keyboard 15 pixels below your `EditText`.
You could also use `ScrollView` as suggested above which allows android to auto handle vertical scrolling for you.

Comment: Actually it probably won't.  WHen you pan for the keyboard, the OS only promises that the cursor will be on screen.  Not the entire edit text with padding.